# Customize row counting on children rows formatter React Tabulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I'm using React Tabulator with Nested data to create data tree table. For example, I have a list of elements with parents and children and **"rownum" formatters**:

1. Parent 1
2. Parent 2

With expanded element in data tree, it will be:

1. Parent 1

   - 0. Children 1
   - 0. Children 2
2. Parent 2

   - 0. Children 1

It displays `0` as row count for the children.

Now I want to add **decimal counting alignment** to the children row numbers with custom formatter function.

How can I achieve this ?

1. Parent 1

   - **1.1.** Children 1
   - **1.2**. Children 2
2. Parent 2

   - **2.2.** Children 1

Image example: [Example](https://ibb.co/L9PQTxj)

I have tried to customize the row count but cannot handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to do this within `tabulator` but, as an alternative, you can process the table data by adding row numbers before loading it into tabulator.  Here is an example:

```js
const tableData = [
  { name: 'Oli Bob', location: 'United Kingdom', gender: 'male', dob: '14/04/1984', _children: [
      { name: 'Mary May', location: 'Germany', gender: 'female', dob: '14/05/1982' },
      { name: 'Christine Lobowski', location: 'France', gender: 'female', dob: '22/05/1982' },
      { name: 'Brendon Philips', location: 'USA', gender: 'male', dob: '01/08/1980', _children: [
          { name: 'Margret Marmajuke', location: 'Canada', gender: 'female', dob: '31/01/1999' },
          { name: 'Frank Harbours', location: 'Russia', gender: 'male', dob: '12/05/1966' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'Jamie Newhart', location: 'India', gender: 'male', dob: '14/05/1985' },
  { name: 'Gemma Jane', location: 'China', gender: 'female', dob: '22/05/1982', _children: [
    { name: 'Emily Sykes', location: 'South Korea', gender: 'female', dob: '11/11/1970' }] },
    { name: 'James Newman', location: 'Japan', gender: 'male', dob: '22/03/1998' }
]

// Add row numbers
const numberRows = (data, rowNum) => {
  data.forEach((row, index) => {
    row.rowNum = (rowNum ? rowNum + '.' : '') + (index + 1)

    if (row._children) {
      numberRows(row._children, row.rowNum)
    }
  })
}

numberRows(tableData)

// Tabulator table
const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  height: '300px',
  data: tableData,
  dataTree: true,
  dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
  columns: [
    { title: '', field: 'rowNum', width: 100, headerSort: false },
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 150 },
    { title: 'Location', field: 'location', width: 140 },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender', width: 100 },
    { title: 'Date Of Birth', field: 'dob', width: 140 }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>
```